# Magic Mock function inside a constructor

Tags: python, testing, mocking

I am writing a test, where I create a constructor.
This constructor has one parameter, which I pass a Mock inside.
But except for this parameter, there is another function inside of the parameter and I'm not sure how to get the constructor to see it as a Mock.
Here's an easy example:

```
Class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, var):
        self._var = var
        self._func()
        # Other stuff, I actually care about and can easily check **
```

Now it's easy to handle the `var` if I pass it as a parameter in the test:

```
def test_trying_mock(self):
    var = MagicMock()
    object = MyClass(var)
```

And the var line is handled. How can I make the constructor see func as mock and make it skip it to the part I actually wanna run and check?

Comment: `self._func = func()` looks like you are setting `_func` to the result of calling `func()`. Is that what's going on here? Or is `self._func` supposed to be a function that will be called?

Comment: where is `func` declared?

Comment: @MarkMeyer Thank you for noticing, you were right and I edited the question. It's just a call for a function which I want to skip.

Comment: @WilliamBright I edited the question. the func() is another method of MyClass

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found out how to do it:

In the testing class, under `set_up`, I added `self._mock_func()`.
Outside of `set_up`, I implemented this function like this:

```
def _mock_func(self):
    class_path = ' [path to MyClass] '
    self._func_mock = self.mock_object('_func', path= class_path)
```

Then, when the constructor runs, it will give this function a mock and keep running.